# How to configure compiler for VIX API with Visual Studio 2012 c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vmware, vmware-tools, vix

Guidance is required to configure Visual Studio 2012 compiler with VIX API. I have already installed VIX API on my computer with Windows 8 64bit operating system.

Can anyone show me step by step how to:

- setup the compiler
- compile samples
- compile my own program

I have already read [VMWare Reference guide](http://www.vmware.com/products/beta/ws/vix_api/ReferenceGuide/) for VIX API.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to walk before you learn to run. If you can't write `Hello, World` yourself, you're not yet ready to deal with VIX.

Comment: ok i wrote a program and i need to compile it. I don't know Visual Studio. I have problems with workspace

Comment: `File>New>New project from existing code`. Or if you want to start from scratch, `File>New>New Project>Win32 console app`.

Comment: Could you also tell me. If i would like to get screenshot (VixVM_CaptureScreenImage). I know that i have to be log as guest(VixVM_LoginInGuest). To log as a Guest had i use VixHost_Connect? or simply only (VixVM_Open)?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the [VMWare Reference guide](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix16_reference/)
1- the first thing you should consider is that you need to work with **wrapper library**

> If you do not use the wrapper, you need to link the appropriate Vix
>   libraries for the VMware product to which your Vix program connects.

2- if you want to work with VS2008 and later version, you must use compile with Dynamic lib.

2.1- righClick on Project >> propertice >> configuration propertice >>c/c++ >> code generation >> runtime library: set to 'Multi-threaded(/MT)'

2.2- righClick on Project >> propertice >> configuration propertice >> linker >> general >> Aditional library Directory: add installed directory of vix to this option . for example:"C:\VMware_VIX"

2.3- in the above path, check 'link library dependencies' and 'use library dependency inputs' option to 'yes'.

2.4- in above linker path, linker >> input >> additional dependencies , add this '.lib' files.

- VixAllProductsDyn.lib
- kernel32.lib
- user32.lib
- advapi32.lib
- ole32.lib
- oleaut32.lib
- ws2_32.lib
- shell32.lib

now , click 'ok'. you can compile and run you program :)